# Autodesk Forge token reauthorization command doesn't recognize parameters

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using Laravel / PHP on the back end to communicate with the Forge system. To establish an initial token, I am using the guzzle tool kit. This works fine.

```
    // Get environment variables
    $FusionID = getenv('THISID');
    $FusionSecret = getenv('THISSECRET');

    // Make call to get token with authorization code, client id, and secret
    $client = new Client(); //GuzzleHttp\Client
    $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/gettoken', [
        'form_params' => [
            'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            'code' => $authCode,
            'client_id' => $FusionID,
            'client_secret' => $FusionSecret,
            'redirect_uri' => 'https://www.example.com/redirect',
            'scope' => array('data'=>'create', 'data'=>'read')
        ]
    ]);
    $body = $response->getBody();
    $obj = json_decode($body);
```

For the numerous other commands, the guzzle protocol seems to have issues so I have been using the straight curl commands. However, I can't seem to get either to work for the refresh token.

I have verified that the variables below have the proper data, but I get the error that

```
"developerMessage":"The required parameter(s) client_id,client_secret,grant_type not present in the request","userMessage":"","errorCode":"AUTH-008",
```

I am not sure what to do. Both the guzzle method and the curl method do not seem to be working for me.

```
        $thumbData = '{"client_id":"'.$FusionID.'", 
          "client_secret":"'.$FusionSecret.'", 
          "grant_type":"refresh_token", 
          "refresh_token":"'.$userInfo->refresh_token.'"}'; 


        $url = 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/refreshtoken';

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,  $thumbData );
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
        ));

        $response = curl_exec ($ch);
        $err = curl_error($ch);
        curl_close ($ch);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you post `x-www-form-urlencoded` data with Guzzle looks fine so that leaves the question to be whether your Guzzle version is 6+ otherwise use `body` instead of `form_params` as your payload option.

With cURL you request body should be delimited by `&` in `x-www-form-urlencoded` format like below instead of `json:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,
            "client_id=sb233&client_secret=2333&...");
```

Comment: I still get the response ... "The authorization code/refresh token is expired or invalid/redirect_uri must have the same value as in the authorization request." The redirect uri is not part of the command and I don't understand how a refresh token can expire.

Comment: When you refresh for a new access token you will be given a new refresh token - use that for your next token refresh and so on

Comment: Yes, I know, but I am getting this response when I send the refresh command. Not sure how to handle that.

Comment: When you get your first refresh token from gettoken that very refresh token could only be used once... if you use it again you will run into this error and then you got no option but start the auth flow all over again

Comment: I have not yet been able to get the refresh token function to work. At all. And yet the error that i get back tells me that the token is old.

Comment: When I tried just now it worked - see [here](https://www.screencast.com/t/uomORl6DB)